# Vaadin 7 security code placement

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

In my Vaadin 7 application I have to add Delete button, but this button should be only accessible to an authorized person.

I have added the button with a following code:

```
if (canRemove()) {
    layout.addComponent(createRemoveButton());
}
```

Also I have added a listener to this button:

```
button.addClickListener(e -> {
    //some logic
});
```

Do I need to add one more condition inside of this listener:

```
button.addClickListener(e -> {
    if (canRemove()) {
        //some logic
    }
});
```

or this condition is redundant and I can avoid it ?

Comment: It's redundant, no button, no click (delete) event

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Pretty much what @AndréSchild said. For example, something simple along the lines of `button.setVisible(isAuthorized(user))` should suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comments on the question:

It's redundant, no button, no click event. Alternative is hiding the button like `button.setVisible(isAuthorized(user))` if not authorized.